# IDA Pro could not disassemble native function properly

Tags: ida, obfuscation, arm64, aarch64

Looks like some obfuscation technique was applied to this piece of code (none of `start` opcodes were identified properly):

[image]

Is it possible to produce manually more readable assembly?

Comment: @Robert, the section is identified as a code (you can see on screen .text), but neither automatic nor manual reinterpretation ain't successful =(

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say for sure without the sample, but I suspect that the code has been encrypted/scrambled, and is decrypted on load, most likely by some function which runs before the entrypoint (e.g. a pointer in `.init_array` or similar).